# Get multiple elements with DOMDocument

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

i need to parse html like :

```
<div class="item"><div class="title">title 1</div><div class="date">day 1</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="title">title 2</div><div class="date">day 2</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="title">title 3</div><div class="date">day 3</div></div>
```

Actually i do something like this :

```
$title = $xpath->query('//div[@class="title"]//text()');
foreach ($title as $title)
{
  $title = trim($title->nodeValue);
}

$date = $xpath->query('//div[@class="date"]//text()');
foreach ($date as $date)
{
  $date = trim($date->nodeValue);
}
```

But with this i take only one item, so i looking for the proper way to get all the items in the same while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to loop over the `item` elements, then find their respective `title` and `date` text.

```
$items = $xpath->query('//div[@class="item"]');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $title = $xpath->evaluate('string(div[@class="title"])', $item);
    $date  = $xpath->evaluate('string(div[@class="date"])', $item);
    echo "$title $date\n";
}
```

[» See the above example running online](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0BZDjY).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your problem. The loops work as expected and you can just accumulate all titles and dates in an array for example. Although I wouldn't reuse the same variable names again.

```
$titles = $xpath->query('//div[@class="title"]//text()');
foreach ($titles as $title)
{
    $all_titles[] = trim($title->nodeValue);
}

$dates = $xpath->query('//div[@class="date"]//text()');
foreach ($dates as $date)
{
    $all_dates[] = trim($date->nodeValue);
}
```

[codepad](http://codepad.org/2YqsDEZy) for testing.